# Apache server no more accessible from outside

Tags: apache, server, xampp, public

I've used apache through xampp for more than a year, to have an access on a simple site in the htdocs folder in my pc and it always worked. During the last month it is no more accesible from the outside and I can't understand why.  
  It has always worked, while now I can see the site going to localhost/, or going to my public ip 93.xx.xx.xx/ on my laptop, or even from other devices from local network wifi, through the public ip. But if I try to access through my 3G connection (or others) it can't reach the site (as it did until july).  
 I tried to disable both windows and router firewall but nothing changed.  
 netstat -a says that port 80 is listening but [this site](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) says that port 80 is closed.  
 I've also tried to change the port (as I did other times) without success   
 Any suggestion?  
Thanks

Comment: From your description it seems like the problem should be in the router port forwarding configuration. I would double check the port FW configuration and make sure there isn't any checkbox you missed that drop connections from WAN port. If you add your router information I might be able to help you more.

Comment: The port fowarding was set exatly as when it worked and other programs which set it automatically worked.
However I tried to change everything uselessly until I did the simplest thing I could: I reset the router.
Now it works perfectly, thank you